# (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x1036be260>

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

i have been trying to deal with this error for a while now tried everything that i could find on google but nothing is helping. The "get_internet_spped "is working fine but it throws an error when this driver is closed. also "tweet_at_provider " works fine when other one is commented that means only one driver is working at a time. How can i fix this issue? I am new to programming so a detailed description would be really helpful.

```
from InternetSpeedTwitterBot import InternetSpeedTwitterBot
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

PROMISED_DOWN= 150
PROMISED_UP= 10
TWITTER_EMAIL= ""
TWITTER_PASSWORD=""
speed_test_link="https://www.speedtest.net/"


bot= InternetSpeedTwitterBot(Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()))
bot.get_internet_speed()
bot.tweet_at_provider(TWITTER_EMAIL,TWITTER_PASSWORD)

import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

class InternetSpeedTwitterBot:

def __init__(self, service_install):
  self.driver= webdriver.Chrome(service= service_install)
  self.down= 0
  self.up= 0

def get_internet_speed(self):
  self.driver.get("https://www.speedtest.net/")
  self.driver.maximize_window()
  time.sleep(5)

  self.driver.find_element(By.CLASS_NAME,"start-text").click()
  time.sleep(60)
  self.speeds= self.driver.find_elements(By.CLASS_NAME,"result-data-large")
  for _ in self.speeds:
    self.down_speed = self.speeds[0].text
    self.up_speed= self.speeds[1].text

  self.driver.quit()



 def tweet_at_provider(self, username, password):
  self.driver.get("https://twitter.com/?lang=en")
  self.driver.maximize_window()
  time.sleep(3)

  self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollBy(0,document.body.scrollHeight)")
  time.sleep(3)

  self.sign_up= self.driver.find_element(By.LINK_TEXT,'Sign in')
  self.sign_up.click()
  time.sleep(4)

  self.username= self.driver.find_element(By.NAME,'text')
  self.username.send_keys(username)
  self.username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  time.sleep(4)

  self.re_username = self.driver.find_element(By.NAME,'text')
  self.re_username.send_keys("ArunaAcharya7")
  self.re_username.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  time.sleep(3)

  self.password= self.driver.find_element(By.NAME,"password")
  self.password.send_keys(password)
  self.password.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)
  time.sleep(5)

  self.status= self.driver.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'.public-DraftStyleDefault- 
  block')
  self.status.send_keys(f"Hey my internet provider why is my internet speed is 
  {self.down_speed} and {self.up_speed} when i pay for 150down/10up? ")
  time.sleep(5)

  self.tweet= self.driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'//*[@id="react- 
  root"]/div/div/div[2]/main/div/div/div/div/div/div[3]
  /div/div[2]/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[3]
  /div/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/span/span')
  self.tweet.click()
  time.sleep(10)

  self.driver.quit()
```

Comment: always put FULL error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not in comments) as text (not screenshot, not link to external portal). There are other useful information in the full error/traceback.

Comment: at the bottom of page with speedtest you can find link to [CLI](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli) - it is tool to get speed as text without using browser. You can always use it with `subprocess.run()`

Answer (score 0):

Simply remove `self.driver.quit()` from `get_internet_speed()` because this makes problem.

OR you have to create again `driver = webdriver.Chrome(...)` in `tweet_at_provider()`.

---

**BTW:**

At the bottom of page with speedtest you can find link to [Speedtest CLI](https://www.speedtest.net/apps/cli) - it is tool to get speed as text without using browser. You can always use it with `subprocess.run()`

It gets text like this (but it has also option to get CSV):

```
Retrieving speedtest.net configuration...
Testing from Orange Swiatlowod (79.163.164.66)...
Retrieving speedtest.net server list...
Selecting best server based on ping...
Hosted by Actus-Info Sp. z o.o. (Wroclaw) [238.28 km]: 20.961 ms
Testing download speed................................................................................
Download: 16.43 Mbit/s
Testing upload speed......................................................................................................
Upload: 39.11 Mbit/s
```

This `CLI` in created in Python so maybe you could even import it in your code.